# Sync Laravel 5.1 relations data with Elasticsearch index

Tags: events, elasticsearch, model, laravel-5.1, observers

I have two models:

**Item** / **ItemTranslation** (one to many relation).

I created **ItemObserver** to sync data with the **Elasticsearch** index for "**created** / **updated** / **deleted**" events.

It works fine for the **Item** model but "**created**" event is triggered before saving something in **ItemTranslation** so I do not have access yet to that data.

The only solution I found is to create another observer for the **ItemTranslation**.

Seems that I need one observer foreach model.

Is there any way to have a common observer to see when something changes in its relations?

It will be hard to maintain the index if I will have data spread in multiple tables and updated "simultaneously" from the same form because I need to care in wich order the data is saved and when I have all the data to rebuild the index.

I could use the **Elasticsearch** **parent-child** approach and I will avoid the problem but I would like to keep the documents as **nested objects**.